# Twilio can't access to the server host by personal computer

Tags: django, web-applications, firewall, twilio

We are trying to use twilio for our web app. Currently we are using our own computer as the server. However, twilio can't access to our computer(it shows 502 error).
2 days ago, we figured out that it was because the firewall in our AT&T router block it. So we went on the router's page and set the firewall as passthrough, and luckily it worked.
But since yesterday, it doesn't work again. The settings didn't change, but it just can't work. We tried to restart the router and connection, it worked once. Now since this morning, no matter how many times we restart, it just doesn't work.
What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Are you using [django-twilio](https://django-twilio.rtfd.org)? Based on your tags - I believe I know how to solve your issue:

Set this variable in your django settings:

```
TWILIO_FORGERY_PROTECTION=False
```

Often the forgery protection will not work if you are running it on a local machine or behind a firewall. If that does not solve it, check out the [Twilio app monitor](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/app-monitor) to see the HTTP response and extra details on why it might be failing.

I hope that helps!